# Get each column count where column value is not NULL

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table and 5 columns in the table. I want row count for each column where column value is not null.

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
1        2        2       2        2
2        2        2       NULL     2     
3        NULL     2       2        NULL
NULL     NULL     2       2        NULL
NULL     NULL     2       2        NULL
```

i should get output like 3,2,5,4,2

Answer (score 6):

The solutions offered did not work for me. I had to modify the code as follows:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(NULLIF(Column1,'')),
COUNT(NULLIF(Column2,'')),
COUNT(NULLIF(Column3,'')),
COUNT(NULLIF(Column4,'')),
COUNT(NULLIF(Column5,''))
FROM Table1
```

Comment: If Column1 is NULLable but has a default value of ie. 'None', consider using NULLIF(COLUMN1, 'None').

Answer (score 5):

How about something like

```
SELECT 
COUNT(Column1),
COUNT(Column2),
COUNT(Column3),
COUNT(Column4),
COUNT(Column5)
FROM Table1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deef8/3)

From [COUNT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement.
>
> COUNT(*) is somewhat different in that it returns a count of the
>   number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain NULL values.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function reference, it just counts non-`NULL` items. So,

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(column1) AS column1,
  COUNT(column2) AS column2,
  COUNT(column3) AS column3,
  COUNT(column4) AS column4,
  COUNT(column5) AS column5
FROM yourtable;
```

should return you the information you want.

Answer (score 2):

I second that above response  - just make sure the field names match of course in the order they are in  in both areas.

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5

from ( select

  sum(column1 is not null) as column1,

  sum(column2 is not null) as column2,

  sum(column3 is not null) as column3,

  sum(column4 is not null) as column4,

  sum(column5 is not null) as column5

from mytable) x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
from ( select
  sum(column1 is not null) as column1,
  sum(column2 is not null) as column2,
  sum(column3 is not null) as column3,
  sum(column4 is not null) as column4,
  sum(column5 is not null) as column5
from mytable) x
```